# Key vfs.fs.size[/,used] in zabbix monitoring not work?

Tags: linux, debian, monitoring, zabbix

I have some hosts in a Template in zabbix for monitoring. All items are work correctly for all hosts except an item **vfs.fs.size[/,used]** just for one of them in zabbix web interface.

The host OS is Debian 7.3 and Zabbix agent version is 2.0.9.

Note: every time i try that key by `zabbix_get` from the host, it work correctly and just in zabbix web interface nothing monitor.

Comment: It, itself solved without any changing in configurations. At last i could not find out the reason of problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also calculate the item by

```
vfs.fs.size[/,total] - vfs.fs.size[/,free]
```

It looks like vfs.fs.size[/,used] has a history of being reported improperly.